# Unity 5 c# Navigation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is that my

```
var tempTarget RtsManager.Current.ScreenPointToMapPosition(Input.mousePosition);
```

get value null for some reason even that i told it to get the value on mouseclick

i tried to see why it doesnt get a value but cant seem to figured out the problem

```
public class RtsManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static RtsManager Current = null;

    public List<PlayerSetupDifinition> Players = new List<PlayerSetupDifinition>();

    public TerrainCollider MapCollider;

    public Vector3? ScreenPointToMapPosition(Vector2 point)

    {
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(point);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (!MapCollider.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            return null;

        return hit.point;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Current = null;

        foreach (var p in Players)
        {
            foreach (var u in p.StartingUnits)
            {
                var go = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(u, p.Location.position, p.Location.rotation);

                if (!p.isAi)
                { go.AddComponent<RightClickNavigation>(); }



            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}


public class RightClickNavigation : Interaction {

    public float RelaxDistance = 5;

    private NavMeshAgent agent;
    private Vector3 target = Vector3.zero;
    private bool selected = false;
    private bool isActive = false;

    public override void Deselect()
    {
        selected = false;
    }

    public override void Select()
    {
        selected = true;
    }

    public void SendToTarget()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(target);
        agent.Resume();
        isActive = true;
    }

    void Start () {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(selected && Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1))
        {


            var tempTarget = RtsManager.Current.ScreenPointToMapPosition(Input.mousePosition);

            if (tempTarget.HasValue)
            {
                target = tempTarget.Value;
                SendToTarget();
            }

        }

        if(isActive && Vector3.Distance(target, transform.position) < RelaxDistance)
        {
            agent.Stop();
            isActive = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post your code here, not as images.

Comment: I just edit the post with the code on it

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I Fix the problem, i had to change  Current = null; to  Current = this;